# Redshift - Not able to connect from local machine

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have the following setup. I have a 2 public subnet's and 4 private subnet's.

- In public subnet I have a OpenVPN and another demo server.
- In private subnet I have one instance.
- I have launched a Redshift Cluster which is not publicly accessible.
  In the cluster subnet group I have selected 3 private subnets (Blue lines connected in image).
- In Redshift security group I have inbound from my OpenVPN, Security Group of my private subnet server and demo server security group.

I am able to connect from my demo server to Redshift, I am also able to connect from my private subnet server to Redshift, But I am not able to connect from my local machine to Redshift and I am connected to my OpenVPN.
What I have missed?

Architecture Diagram:

[image]

I am getting the following error :

```
error setting/closing connection connection refused
```

Comment: Firewall issue maybe. Check if the redshift port is blocked.

Comment: I don't think so because our other team can access their Redshift Cluster from our network.

Comment: You have missed something otherwise it would work, however it is too complex to debug for you like this (IMHO). AWS support may be able to help you, or you need to hire someone to come in to your network to debug for you.

Comment: any update on this?